# What is a good way to capture a TextReader in a closure but still dispose of it properly?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures

This is a simplified example, to isolate the purpose of the question. In my actual scneario, the ColumnReader returned by GetColumnReader will actually do more work than merely ReadLine.

If I run the following program, I will get an error when I try to call Reader(), because of course the TextReader has already been disposed by the using statement.

```
public class Play{
    delegate string ColumnReader();
    static ColumnReader GetColumnReader(string filename){
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)){
            var headers = reader.ReadLine();
            return () => reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        var Reader = GetColumnReader("Input.tsv");
        Console.WriteLine(Reader());
    }


}
```

Alternatively, I can remove the "using" and directly declare the TextReader, which would function, but now we no longer have a guarantee that the TextReader will be eventually closed.

Is there a way to add a "destructor" to the returned lambda function where I might be able to Dispose of the TextReader as soon as the lambda function goes out of scope (no more references)?

I also welcome other suggestions but wish to keep the basic closure structure (that is, fits into the scope of the question).

Comment: 1) using { } is a good way to dispose 2) I cannot see the implementation of Reader()

Comment: @HatSoft, 2? "var Reader = GetColumnReader" ... Obviously unusual casing on local variable name, but it is still valid...

Comment: Do you need to call Reader() closure once or multiple times?

Comment: @Smilediver, I may need to call it multiple times, but not necessarily until the file is finished.

Comment: Use an iterator instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need the scope of the disposable element outside of the delegate itself. In these  situations I would make the delegate accept the disposable instance (I.e. TextReader) rather than a file name.

Comment: I like this solution because it makes intuitive sense that the scope of the Disposable is controlled by the method ultimately using it...that is, the method invoking the closure.

Answer (score 3):

If you would not require lambda expression you could create enumerable instead.

Potentially moving using inside the =>{} may work in real code... Still probably not what you are looking for:

```
static ColumnReader GetColumnReader(string filename) {
   return () => {
     using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
        var headers = reader.ReadLine();
        return reader.ReadLine();
     }
  };
}
```

Version with IEnumerable (if you alway finish iteration):

```
 static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnReader(string filename) {
   using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader("aa")) {
     var headers = reader.ReadLine();
     yield return reader.ReadLine();
   }
 }
```

You'll need to create custom IDisposable iterator if you want to support iterations to the middle of the enumeration. See how [`foreach` handles iterators that implement IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Play {

    delegate string ColumnReader();

    static ColumnReader GetColumnReader(string filename) {
        return () => {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
                var headers = reader.ReadLine();
                return reader.ReadLine();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var Reader = GetColumnReader("Input.tsv");
        Console.WriteLine(Reader());
    }


}
```

Obviously, this will open / read one line / close the file every time you call the returned delegate.

If you need to open it once, and then keep it open while reading through several lines, you'll be better off with an iterator block, similar to this:

```
public class Play {

    static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string filename) {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
            var headers = reader.ReadLine(); // I'm guessing you want to ignore this??
            while (true) {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    yield break;
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        foreach (string line in ReadLines("Input.tsv"))
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to preserve the closure semantics, you will need to add an argument for it. Something like bellow, but you have to take care of calling the dispose command.

```
public class Play {
    enum ReaderCommand {
        Read,
        Close
    }

    delegate string ColumnReader(ReaderCommand cmd);

    static ColumnReader GetColumnReader(string filename) {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
        var headers = reader.ReadLine();
        return (ReaderCommand cmd) => {
            switch (cmd) {
                case ReaderCommand.Read:
                    return reader.ReadLine();

                case ReaderCommand.Close:
                    reader.Dispose();
                    return null;
            }

            return null;
        };
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var Reader = GetColumnReader("Input.tsv");
        Console.WriteLine(Reader(ReaderCommand.Read));
        Console.WriteLine(Reader(ReaderCommand.Read));
        Reader(ReaderCommand.Close);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is this any easier than simply returning the TextReader? Seems to me you're making things much more complicated just to achieve a particular coding style.

The onus will always be on the caller to dispose of whatever is returned correctly.
I'm sure your project will give you plenty of opportunity to flex your muscles - this time just keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

I really like the yield solution. I have wirten a simple code, it shows it works well, the resouce can be disposed, after client out of for-each.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (Resource resource = new Resource())
    {
       foreach (var number in resource.GetNumbers())
       {
          if (number > 2)
             break;
          Console.WriteLine(number);
       }
     }
     Console.Read();
 }
 public class Resource : IDisposable
 {
    private List<int> _numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
    {
       foreach (var number in _numbers)
          yield return number;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Resource::Dispose()...");
    }
 }
```